# Hibernate native query : Invalid Column Name Error SQL-17006

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

```
package com.abc.def.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.Serializable;



@NamedNativeQuery(name="getMetadata",query="
                  select a.name alias1,a.fullname alias2,
                         b.name alias3,b.age alias4,
                         c.height alias5,c.something alias6,
                         d.otherthing alias7
                  from lame_table_name a,
                       lame_table_name_2 b
                  where a.id = b.id
                     and b.id = c.id 
                     and c.id = d.id 
                     and d.id = :namedparameter
                  order by a.index,b.index
               ",
            resultClass=MetadataModel.class)


  @Entity
  @IdClass(SomeIdClass.class)

  public class MetadataModel{

  @Id @Column("alias1")
  private Type alias1property;

  @Id @Column("alias2")
  private Type2 alias2property;

  @Column("alias3")
  private Type3 alias3property;

  //getters and setters
  }

  @Embeddable
  class SomeIdClass implements Serializable{

  //serialVersionUID line

  @Id @Column("alias1")
  private Type alias1property;

  @Id @Column("alias2")
  private Type2 alias2property;

  //getter and setters
  }
```

The error is SQL-17006, Invalid Column Name, have been trying out variations of this setup the whole day
Should I try putting Column("lame_table_name.name")

I also tried using SqlResultSetMapping (and removed @Column from fields of POJO) (and specifying all the column aliases in the columns attribute of SqlResultSetMapping) (are we supposed to specify the resultsetmapping again when executing the query via the setResultSetMapping method of the SQLQuery interface?)

```
package com.abc.def.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.Serializable;
//other imports for the SqlResultSetMapping



@NamedNativeQuery(name="getMetadata",query="
                  select a.name alias1,a.fullname alias2,
                         b.name alias3,b.age alias4,
                         c.height alias5,c.something alias6,
                         d.otherthing alias7
                  from lame_table_name a,
                       lame_table_name_2 b
                  where a.id = b.id
                     and b.id = c.id 
                     and c.id = d.id 
                     and d.id = :namedparameter
                  order by a.index,b.index
               ",
            resultSetMapping="metaDataMapping")


@SqlResultSetMapping(name="metaDataMapping",
              entities=@EntityResult(entityClass=MetadataModel.class,
                fields = {@FieldResult(name="alias1Property",column="alias1")
                           //so on
                      }

                 )
            )

  @Entity
  @IdClass(SomeIdClass.class)

  public class MetadataModel{


  private Type alias1property;


  private Type2 alias2property;


  private Type3 alias3property;

  //getters and setters
  }

  //composite class, exactly as above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, earlier I was trying to specify both the columns and entities attributes in the resultsetmapping, so I tried removing the entity mappings, keeping the columns attribute, and calling the aliastobean result transformer, that plus writing setters to accept BigDecimal instead of Long (since its an Oracle DB), solved the issue...

Answer (score 26):

We should have all the table columns in the Select list for oracle..
If we keep only few columns.
Eg,
 your table Employee has columns FirstName,LastName, EmpId,
and if you have query like .

```
session.createSQLQuery("Select FirstName from Employee");
```

the above query won't work. it will throw Invalid column error Exception.
So better put all the columns in Select clause for Oracle.

Courtesy :
[one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321547/native-sql-throwing-invalid-column-name-exception?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Thanks,
Rajesh.

Comment: Thank You. I almost spent whole day resolving this issue and finally got the solution here.

Comment: Welcome Derick .

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Column(name = "myprop")` instead. Also note that Type/Type2/Type3 must be Simple types (Integer/Long/String/Date usually).

Comment: yeah, they are all one of Long,String,Date

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my I needed to give an inner-select body a name, as it was mysteriously truncating away a CASE column.

The following did not work - for some reason COLUMN_B gets mysteriously removed:

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_A,
  CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END as COLUMN_B,
  COLUMN_C
FROM (
   ...
)
```

Then following fixed the problem:

```
SELECT
  RES.COLUMN_A,
  CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END as COLUMN_B,
  RES.COLUMN_C
FROM (
   ...
) RES
```

The whole SQL is only dealing with one table.

Java code:

```
// The "sql" variable is the SQL statement shown above.
javax.persistence.Query res = myEntityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, SomeClass.class);
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.3 with JPA and Oracle 12c.